# What is preferred method for searching table data using stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, search

I have a `customer` table with `Cust_Id`, `Name`, `City` and search is based upon any or all of the above three.

Which one Should I go for ?

1. Dynamic SQL:

   ```
   declare @str varchar(1000)
   set @str = 'Select [Sno],[Cust_Id],[Name],[City],[Country],[State] 
               from Customer where 1 = 1'
   if (@Cust_Id != '')
       set @str = @str + ' and Cust_Id    =  ''' + @Cust_Id + ''''
   if (@Name != '')
       set @str = @str + ' and Name like ''' + @Name + '%'''
   if (@City  != '')
       set @str = @str + ' and City like ''' + @City + '%'''
   exec (@str)
   ```
2. Simple query:

   ```
   select
       [Sno],[Cust_Id],[Name],[City],[Country],[State]
   from
       Customer
   where
       (@Cust_Id  = '' or Cust_Id    =  @Cust_Id) and
       (@Name     = '' or Name     like @Name + '%') and
       (@City     = '' or City     like @City + '%')
   ```

Which one should I prefer (1 or 2) and what are advantages?

**After going through everyone's suggestion , here is what i finally got.**

```
  DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(1000)
  DECLARE @ParametersDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
  SET @ParametersDefinition = N'@InnerCust_Id varchar(10),
                              @InnerName varchar(30),@InnerCity varchar(30)'


 SET @str = 'Select [Sno],[Cust_Id],[Name],[City],[Country],[State]
                                          from Customer where 1 = 1'

 IF(@Cust_Id != '')
    SET @str = @str + ' and Cust_Id = @InnerCust_Id'
 IF(@Name != '')
    SET @str = @str + ' and Name like @InnerName'
 IF(@City  != '')
    SET @str = @str + ' and City like @InnerCity'


-- ADD the % symbol for search based upon the LIKE keyword
SELECT  @Name = @Name + '%', @City = @City+ '%'

EXEC sp_executesql @str, @ParametersDefinition,
                      @InnerCust_Id = @Cust_Id,
                      @InnerName    = @Name,
                      @InnerCity    = @City;
```

**Note** : `@Cust_Id`, `@Name` and  `@City` are parameters being passed to the stored procedure

References :
  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/changing-exec-to-sp_executesql-doesn-t-p

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx

Comment: Your dynamic SQL version is vulnerable to SQL injection. If you do decide to go that route use `sp_executesql` and parameterised queries. See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: @MartinSmith , on your suggestion i searched and found an article regarding sp_executesql usage over EXEC and how it increases the performance , its worth reading. Here is the link http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/changing-exec-to-sp_executesql-doesn-t-p

Comment: @ALL , with everyone's suggestion and referring few links i have modified the search logic, but iam not sure where should i post it, 
shall i edit the question and attach the logic at the end or post it as answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic SQL can be a little more difficult to write, and it is vulnerable to SQL Injection if you are not careful.  However, it outperforms the "non-dynamic"/Simple or query.

Read more about it here.  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/do-you-use-column-param-or-param-is-null

Comment: simpe query also can be susceptible to parameter sniffing issue. but definitely a more readable/manage-able solution.

Comment: @G Mastros , thanks for the link, it is really helpful to me.

Comment: @sam yi, the sumple query is more readable and can be easily managed. but the link provided by "G Mastros" says that "Dynamic Query" are good for performance.

Comment: @Mourya: Yes dynamic query has better perf... that's what I meant by the parameter sniffing (sub optimal plan) problem.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic SQL is likley to be more performant which is generally important in a search.

However, it is more diffiult to write and debug and test. First you need to make sure it will not allow SQL injection attacks. Next you need to make sure that the variables you use are large enough to contain the largest possible final SQl statement you would create.

Then you need to create a good number of test cases to make sure that there is not some sort of subtle bug.

You will also need to grant read permissions to the underlying tables which you normally don't need to do if you use Stored procs.

Finally when doing dynamic SQL in a stored proc, please add an input variable called @debug as the last input variable and give it a default value of 0. When a 1 is passed in, instead of executing the dynamic SQL, it will send you the SQL that is created. This will help you debug the proc and and is especially helpful when there is a an error in some future search because you can see exactly what SQL was run for those values.

Comment: i will use the "@debug" variable in my procedures , thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Dynamic SQL makes sense (gains performance) only of decreases the number of JOINs.

Otherwise it only worsen code readability and maintainability.

Comment: Disagree. [Catch-all queries](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) generally have sub optimal plans (at least unless `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is used)

Comment: @Martin: Agree. Thanks. Actually I was talking about the same case, but didn't knew the actual reason of performance hit.